# Perl Mojolicious minion->enqueue with custom-id

Tags: perl, uuid, mojolicious

According to [Minion](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Minion/#enqueue1):

```perl
my $id = $minion->enqueue(foo => [@args]);
```

Is it possible to use a custom-id? For example:

```perl
my $id = Data::UUID->new->create_str;
$self->minion->enqueue(foo => [@args] => {id => $id});
```

Similar to the [`LinkCheck`](https://github.com/mojolicious/minion/tree/main/examples/linkcheck) example, I don't want users to see "other" users' URLs as the `id` is easily guessable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. `enqueue` gets its ID from [`Minion::Backend::Pg::enqueue`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Minion/source/lib/Minion/Backend/Pg.pm#L35-46), which itself gets the ID by doing an SQL insert query that ends with [`RETURNING id`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html), which means that the ID returned by `enqueue` is the ID of the row inserted into the database.

---

Instead, you could use a hash mapping the IDs returned by `enqueue` to the GUIDs generated by `Data::UUID`. Something like:

```
my $internal_id = $minion->enqueue(foo => [@args]);
my $external_id = Data::UUID->new->create_str;
$self->extern_to_intern_map{$external_id} = $internal_id;
```

(note that `extern_to_intern_map` will grow without ever shrinking; if your application is running for a long time, you may want to explicitly `delete` old mappings)

Comment: Thanks @Dada. Does the same apply to other DBs? (e.g. SQLite?) And do the Minion jobs (Finished, Failed or Inactive) expire after sometime and are removed from the queue?